# How to keep iPhone 4- formatting on iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, screen

So I am developing apps for the iphone 4s-, but I want iPhone 5 users to be able to access the app as well.

I want to make it so that if the user has an iPhone 5, it just has the little black bars at the top and bottom that you see in some other apps (I basically want to keep the formatting for the 3.5 inch screen.

Is there a way to test iPhone 5 on the simulator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try deleting the default launch screen of the 4" display from the app summary. I think that shall do it

Comment: Thanks ill try that and let you know if it works.  Is there a way to test iPhone 5 on the simulator? cuz i can only run 4

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to test iPhone 5 on the simulator? Because I can only run 4

*iPhone (Retina 4-inch)* equals the iPhone 5

[image: screenshot]